# write a function that invokes as a result of setting setDelegate:self

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I understand how to create my own delegate, but don't know how to write a method for the following situation

I'm setting a popover

```
NotesViewController *viewControllerForPopover =(NotesViewController*)
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotesPopover"];


popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
           initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
[popover setPopoverContentSize:viewControllerForPopover.size];
[popover setDelegate:self];
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem: p_barButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

in this line `[popover setDelegate:self];` I make sure that when the popover disappears it will "return" to the current viewController, but how can I set a function to be invoked with that delegate?

Comment: Returning to the current VC is not meant to be invoked in setDelegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:
in the UIViewController interface make sure you have the protocol `<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>` if not add it

then in the implementation file write this function

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    //do the stuff needed after the popover was closed
}
```